# Reload Parent's Div with Another Div Inside Parent

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dom

Is it possible to manipulate a div inside of a page from another div inside that page using JQuery?

For ex. index.php contains `<div id="test">` and `<div id="test2">`. Div named "test" loads test.php and "test2" loads test2.php. Is it possible to reload test's content from test2?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far? Could you show a more structured example of your markup?

Comment: Can you share some code examples here? It would be helpful to see the HTML and the jQuery that is loading this content.

Comment: I simply didn't know that i can communicate with parent page's element ids, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. This line will reload div#test by loading test.php

```
$("#test").load("test.php");
```